Wierd things happening on my Ubuntu 22.04LTS
okey not sure what is happening but i start from Wayland settings
this was fresh installation after it finally got installed 8 times it crashed on after selecting automatic LVM partition even tried 23.10 and it crashed after installation and full partition and files fried wouldent boot anymore this happened 10 times on 10 installations
i cant get NVIDIA/Intel hybrid to work on Wayland it only uses mesa intel or if i install libnvidia-egl-wayland1 then my NVIDIA is only working no mesa intel so went back to xorg where everything works.
after that i was where is my nautilus did not find it anywhere and had to install it again and after that it was back as normal
after updates and some software installation i lost Gnome settings so again thought somehow it got uninstalled or something so installed gnome-control-center and again it came back and all good
this is something i can't understand or think what and how things keep getting uninstalled on system even i just install deb apps and run updates to system

Found what was causing Gnome settings uninstallation and it is caused installing DaVinci Resolve that needs FUSE to be installed and FUSE installation removes Gnome settings especially Gnome Settings seems like it also uninstall/deletes some more settings especially desktop icons/desktop Home settings are gone not that i am missing this, but it means there might be still more missing after installing fuse and then re-installing gnome settings still have missing settings on settings field
